# Return a value stored in Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I read several answers about this problem, but I still have null in the answer of Firebase Android App. One of them was:

[Firebase retrieve/read returns null values - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36360779/firebase-retrieve-read-returns-null-values-android)

My problem:

I can write into Firebase but I cannot read the values.

I try:

1 change the values of Firebase rules from:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

to:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

but did not worked, I can write but cannot read values.

My code:

```
 private void postComment() {
        //final String uid = getUid();
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users")/*.child("KU1y_SLZGLZpJB2j_Pc")*/
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        // Get user information
                        UserClassGu user = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserClassGu.class);
                        String authorName = user.name;
                        Log.d(TAG,"name read into postCopmment = "+authorName);


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
    }
```

This is my Class used in getValue(UserClassGu.class)

/**
 * Created by Cliente on 14/10/2016.
 */

```
public class UserClassGu {

    public String userUid;
    public   String email;
    public String name;
    public String telephone;

    public UserClassGu() {

    }

    public String getUserUid() {
        return userUid;
    }

    public UserClassGu(String userUid, String email, String name, String telephone) {
        userUid = userUid;
        this.email = email;
        this.name = name;
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }

    public void setUserUid(String userUid) {
        userUid = userUid;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getTelephone() {
        return telephone;
    }

    public void setTelephone(String telephone) {
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }


}
```

My database:

```
{
  "messages" : {
    "-KU87z9hSXew-Li37xgF" : {
      "destinatario" : "ad@g.com",
      "name" : "app app",
      "photoUrl" : "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-jjv4PSa0NzA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/APaXHhQm8WxqRupmfbe87U11m9pfn9C9ag/s96-c/photo.jpg",
      "text" : "hello"
    },
    "-KU88ciYGXz39PZGZW98" : {
      "destinatario" : "rere",
      "name" : "app app",
      "photoUrl" : "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-jjv4PSa0NzA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/APaXHhQm8WxqRupmfbe87U11m9pfn9C9ag/s96-c/photo.jpg",
      "text" : "adafa"
    }
  },
  "messages_private" : {
    "rere" : {
      "553xVAMEVcQZPKNVqfal8S9tOM03" : {
        "-KU88ciZUNQkCskad6Xc" : {
          "destinatario" : "rere",
          "name" : "app app",
          "photoUrl" : "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-jjv4PSa0NzA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/APaXHhQm8WxqRupmfbe87U11m9pfn9C9ag/s96-c/photo.jpg",
          "text" : "adafa"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "-KU3ZlBN-gmHZOhg74-M" : {
      "email" : "app@gmail.com",
      "name" : "app app",
      "telephone" : ""
    },
    "-KU3_ZjTHJHprd36xT1u" : {
      "email" : "appa@gmail.com",
      "name" : "app app",
      "telephone" : ""
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: You're not handling errors in `onCancelled`. See http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase/5548/how-do-i-listen-for-errors-when-accessing-the-database/22652/detect-errors-when-reading-data-on-android#t=201610150548314420923

Comment: I added this method like you suggested, but still is returning null: public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
                    Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                    throw databaseError.toException();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved changing the path of the data into Firebase:

Into the Class UserGu:

1. I forgot to write the getter getUserUid()

   public String getUserUid() {
       return userUid;
   }

2.The path of the database Firebase for the data I wanted to read was not ok:
I changed to: 
          mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("users").child(mUserUid).setValue(userClassGu);

```
UserClassGu userClassGu = UserClassGu(mUserUid,mUserEmail,mUsername,"");   



            mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("users").child(mUserUid).setValue(userClassGu);


            //Write data of users
            mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("users").child(mUserUid).setValue(userClassGu);


            //Reading the data


mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("users").child(mUserUid).addValueEventListener(
                new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        // Get user value
                        UserClassGu userClassgu = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserClassGu.class);
                        Log.d(TAG,"reading data  :userClassgu.email = "+userClassgu.email);
                        Log.d(TAG,"reading data  :userClassgu.name: = "+userClassgu.name);
                        Log.d(TAG,"reading data  :userClassgu.telephone: = "+userClassgu.telephone);
                        Log.d(TAG,"reading data  :userClassgu.userUid: = "+userClassgu.userUid);
                        // ...
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "getUser:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                        // ...
                    }
                });
```

In the class userClassGu I put the method:

```
@Exclude
public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
    HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put("uid", userUid);
    result.put("email", email);
    result.put("name", name);
    result.put("telephone", telephone);
    return result;
}
```

I put int the class UserClassGuthe text:
@IgnoreExtraProperties

The code of the class userClassGu became:

```
package com.sciencesoftware.friends;

import com.google.firebase.database.Exclude;
import com.google.firebase.database.IgnoreExtraProperties;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by Cliente on 14/10/2016.
 */
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class UserClassGu {
    public String userUid;
    public   String email;
    public String name;
    public String telephone;

    public UserClassGu() {
// Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(UserClassGu.class)

    }

    public UserClassGu(String userUid, String email, String name, String telephone) {
        this.userUid = userUid;
        this.email = email;
        this.name = name;
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }


    public String getUserUid() {
        return userUid;
    }





    public void setUserUid(String userUid) {
        this.userUid = userUid;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getTelephone() {
        return telephone;
    }

    public void setTelephone(String telephone) {
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }


    @Exclude
    public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
        HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("uid", userUid);
        result.put("email", email);
        result.put("name", name);
        result.put("telephone", telephone);
        return result;
    }



}
```

3.
This is the JSON of Firebase:

```
{
  "users" : {
    "Bl0AiMMUXsV2H58lqoj0rO8457j1" : {
      "email" : "myEmail@gmail.com",
      "name" : "my name",
      "telephone" : "",
      "userUid" : "Bl0AiMMUXsV2H58lqoj0rO8457j1"
    }
  }
}
```

Studding the documentation :
The class that will have the data put into the database must:
1 Have a Constructor empty:
2 have a constructor with all the arguments of the variables  -(I am not absolutely right about this)
The Variables of the class must be public or must have all getters public(I am not absolutely right about this). 
3 have all the getters. 
4 the setter are not necessary.

I will be happy if somebody correct me if i said something wrong about this 4 things above.